# Can't make docker-compose work like dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nuxt.js

I'm trying to deploy a Nuxt.js application within a Docker container and in most of the tutorials, it is asked to create a Dockerfile with this content:

```
FROM node:alpine

ENV APP_ROOT /app

RUN mkdir ${APP_ROOT}
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}
ADD . ${APP_ROOT}

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
```

And then use this to build the actual image of the project, but this process takes too long because it needs to copy the whole project to the working directory. So i thought in writing all this in the `docker-compose.yml` file like so:

```
version: "3"

services:
  frontend:
    image: node:alpine
    container_name: website_frontend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      HOST: 0.0.0.0
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
    restart: always
    command: sh -c "npm install && npm run build && npm run start"
```

But it is not working as I get the status `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Usually the mechanics of `docker build` are pretty quick for me — the overhead of running `docker build` is usually less than the cost of running `webpack` once.  Restructuring the `Dockerfile` to not re-run `npm install` on every build will help (copy only the `package.json` and lock file first, then run `npm install`, then copy the application).

Comment: While I can't use only docker-compose to achieve it, I will do that. And I've also managed to include a `.dockerignore` file to ignore `node_modules` folder when making the copy, which makes it really faster. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

I did few changes in the above `docker-compose.yml`; if it doesn't work, there should be an issue with the npm build.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  frontend:
    container_name: website_frontend
    image: node:alpine
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - HOST=0.0.0.0
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
    command: bash -c "npm install && npm run build && npm run start"
    restart: always
```

Comment: In my case this was problem with folders (working_dir and volumes). Thanks for the answer! Helped me a lot!